# Create type of struct by assignment instead of initialization

Tags: swift

In Swift, there are various types such as `Int`, `String`, etc. that allow initialization by assignment. For example:

```
var myInt = 0
var myInt: Int = 5
```

I'd like to create my own type where I can do the same:

```
var myTypeVariable = 1
var myTypeVariable: MyType = 7
```

But it only allows me to create a new variable of `MyType` by initializing a `MyType` first then assigning it:

```
var myTypeVariable = MyType(7)
```

Is it possible to set a variable of `MyType` with a value?

Comment: If your question has been answered, please mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep.

```
extension MyType: ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral {
    init(integerLiteral: Int) { self.value = integerLiteral }
}
```

See:

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/swift_standard_library/initialization_with_literals
- and https://nshipster.com/swift-literals/